# Group pandas dataframe values by ID and map the operations on values ( assign single workers per ID)

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a large DataFrame and I want to map operations on groups of values to speed it up.

Currently I use Transform(). This is how I would do it for a small DataFrame.

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,2,2,3,3], 'Value':[.1,.4,.5,.9,.1,.3]})
def myfunc(x):
    return x/x.sum()
df.groupby('ID').transform(myfunc)
```

I want to map the operations so it is done in parallel per IDs. Thank you in advance.

Comment: before parallelizing, does `.transform` approach actually lead to unacceptable processing time?

Comment: `df['Value']/df.groupby('ID')['Value'].transform('sum')` is a bit faster.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes. It takes unreasonably long.

Comment: @QuangHoang The operation I do on the values is different than what I presented. I wanted my example to be to be simple.